# How to configure eclipse with GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github

I am following the steps mentioned under "http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/" but I am getting error each time the installation started

My eclipse version is: Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

and the error I am getting is:

```
> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
> context was:(profile=C__Users_Ahmad_eclipse_java-neon_eclipse,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
> action=). No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,4.7.1.201706071930-r No repository found
> containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,4.7.1.201706071930-r No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,4.7.1.201706071930-r No repository
> found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.feature,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.ui,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.ui.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui.smartimport,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.lfs,4.7.1.201706071930-r No repository
> found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.lfs,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.server,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.pgm,4.7.1.201706071930-r No repository
> found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.pgm,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r No repository
> found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.source,4.7.1.201706071930-r
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.ui,4.7.1.201706071930-r
```